# Install Windows 10 and Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS on Raid 1 (2 disks)

Tags: system-installation, windows-10, raid

I have 2 SSD M.2 disk (samsung 980 pro 1 tb), configured as RAID 1 (in bios).

I want install windows 10 and ubuntu desktop 20.04 LTS (1 Tb partition for each os).

**how can i do it properly?**

I installed win 10 sucsessfully on full space (2 Tb) partition,
and when i tried install ubuntu, i see two disks instead of one.

**May be i need special drivers, like at windows?**

And should i create 50% partition when installing windows and do not try to resize, while installing ubuntu?

Comment: Only one windows 10 and only one ubuntu desktop

Comment: I installed 22.04 on a Windows system with 11th Gen Intel and  RAID on. Forget to turn it off and it installed without issue with VMD driver. It is using the Intel Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller in hardware list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel Raid w/Optane (usually what you are referring to) is completely unsupported in any Linux distribution, so it will never work. Really nothing more to discuss.

The only raids you can have on Linux are:

1. MD Raids (software), built into the kernel.
2. Hardware Controller Raids for supported controllers. (For servers.)
3. Raids created via certain filesystems like LVM (really #1 with another layer), BTRFS/ZFS

If you're already installed Windows into that raid, you have to go into your bios and turn it off by switching on AHCI mode on the disks. After that you go back and reinstall the Windows, then the Ubuntu. If you want to configure a soft-raid (aka #1) you have to use the Ubuntu Server installer and go through the steps. If you are new to Ubuntu, which I presume you are by asking that question, then you likely will not be very comfortable with the text mode installer that the Ubuntu Server gives you. You will have to partition the raid by hand even in that installer and know what you're doing or you won't get it to work. Probably not something to do if this is your only computer or your first time around.

There is no workaround for the "Intel Raid" situation presently, but back in the day there used to be a Phoenix raid bios that used to work because it emulated the software of an actual raid controller and it worked. That was only available for AMD platforms back in the day, however. Anyway, that was the only time it ever worked. I'd imagine it still works if you had that hardware, but otherwise it just doesn't. :D

Comment: thx for answer. 

it looks like I wasted money on buying two ssd m2 to organize a raid array under ubuntu

Comment: @user1272025 Nope, but you maybe would waste some storage if you did it. You can certainly do it, but what you can't have is raid on BOTH operating systems. You have to pick one to control the raid essentially. I am running RAID1 on this machine here in that exact configuration, but I am not loading windows. If the reason you are dual booting isn't games, just run the Windows in a virtual machine. The only reason to have the windows partition is to load games.

Comment: @user1272025 option B is something like, make a Windows partition on both drives with the AHCI activated. Store the games one, the operating system and programs on the other. Configure the Ubuntu into a raid for the remainder of both disks. It just depends on how much you need Windows.

Personally, I don't use Windows at all and do everything on Linux including games. :D

Comment: @user1272025 Option C: Install a Virtual Machine to run the Ubuntu on the single boot Windows Intel Raid. (My opinion of what is the best option). When you need Ubuntu you fire up the VM and go fullscreen, it'll feel just like you're there. Meanwhile you will have the speed advantage of the existing raid. Virtualbox is free, download and install, configure the VM extensions/drive (you can make it growable) and bam you''re done. You won't even be able to tell you're running it in a vm. Ubuntu is rather small in comparison to Windows...

Comment: i use windows for games and ubuntu for work. now, i removed vmd control at bios, and made software raid at ubuntu. i have one more ssd m2 disk, and now window work on it. its not critical to loose performance at windows. thx everyone for help